# Как определить вызван ли триггер действиями процедуры

Tags: sql-server, триггер, stored-procedures

суть: нужно определить вызван ли триггер действиями хранимой процедуры, и если да то ничего с этим не делать. отключать триггер на время исполнения процедуры нельзя

Вот код которым я пытаюсь поймать процедуру

```
   CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TR_PRC_CATCHER
   ON  dbo.TABLE
   FOR INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
IF OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) not like '%procedure%'
 BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Поймал!', 16, 1) WITH SETERROR;
 END
END
```

правильный ли это метод, или можно решить данный вопрос лаконичнее

upd:
проверил данный метод, @@procid выдает object_id самого триггера а не процедуры, которой он был вызван.

Данный вариант рабочим не является

Comment: Нужно чтобы триггер срабатывал только для конкретной процедуры? Или чтобы для процедуры (любой) срабатывал, а без процедуры не срабатывал?

Comment: Да, чтобы триггер пропускал действия определенной процедуры

Comment: Оформите пожалуйста ответ с примером, поставлю что вопрос решен, я так понимаю что речь о "context_info()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> нужно определить вызван ли триггер действиями хранимой процедуры

В SqlServer нет встроенных средств, которые помогли бы понять, что триггер выполняется в контексте определённой процедуры. На Feedback.Azure размещён [запрос](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32891353-provide-function-to-retrieve-the-entire-call-stack) (датирующийся аж 2006 годом) на добавление функции, которая давала бы информацию о стеке вызовов. Текущий статус запроса -  *UNPLANNED*. Поэтому в данном случае придётся что-то изобретать и, видимо, без изменений в процедуре не обойтись.

Предположим, что `[Table]` - таблица, на которой будет триггер.

```
CREATE TABLE [Table]
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    SomeDate datetime2(0) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Table PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

Для примера я буду использовать `AFTER INSERT` триггер, а процедура, соответственно, будет делать `INSERT` в эту таблицу.

Нужно сообщить триггеру каким-либо способом, что его вызов происходит в контексте определённой процедуры.

**Вариант #1** - Использование временной таблицы

Внутри процедуры создаём временную таблицу

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TestProc
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #TestProc_Context(Dummy int);

    INSERT INTO [Table] (SomeDate)
    VALUES (SYSDATETIME());
END
```

а в триггере проверяем её наличие и делаем (или не делаем) что-то, в зависимости от этого

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER Table_AfterInsert ON [Table]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestProc_Context') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'In TestProc.';
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Not in TestProc';
        RETURN;
    END;
END
```

Проверяем работоспособность

```
INSERT INTO [Table] (SomeDate)
VALUES (SYSDATETIME());
GO
EXEC TestProc;
GO
```

Этот вариант видится мне наименее проблемным, т.к. после выхода из процедуры, что бы ни случилось, временная таблица будет уничтожена автоматически. Если нет высоких требований к throughput, то я бы порекомендовал остановиться на этом варианте. Если требования к производительности высокие, и в этом варианте ощутимо сказывается tempdb contention, то следующий вариант будет более предпочтительным.

**Вариант #2** - Использование контекста сессии

В начале процедуры устанавливаем контекст, а перед выходом сбрасываем

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TestProc
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC sp_set_session_context @key = N'TestProc_Context', @value = 1;

    INSERT INTO [Table] (SomeDate)
    VALUES (SYSDATETIME());

    EXEC sp_set_session_context @key = N'TestProc_Context', @value = NULL;
END
```

в триггере, аналогично, проверяем наличие контекста

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER Table_AfterInsert ON [Table]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF SESSION_CONTEXT(N'TestProc_Context') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Not in TestProc';
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'In TestProc.';
        RETURN;
    END;
END
```

В первом варианте автоматическое уничтожение временной таблицы после выхода из процедуры так же автоматически сбрасывает контекст. В этом же варианте контекст сбрасывается вручную, поэтому очень важно, чтобы сброс произошёл. В реальной процедуре с более сложным кодом может потребоваться блок `TRY...CATCH...`, если возможно возникновение ошибок в промежутке между установкой и сбросом контекста.

Функционал `sp_set_session_context` и `SESSION_CONTEXT` доступен в SqlServer 2016 и более поздних версиях. В более ранних версиях, теоретически, можно воспользоваться `SET CONTEXT_INFO` и `CONTEXT_INFO`, но я бы этот вариант не рекомендовал, если нет уверенности, что не будет пересечений ни с какими другими процессами, которые гипотетически также могут использовать `CONTEXT_INFO`.

Answer (score 0):

Если процедура создаёт или изменяет запись в таблице, чем вызывает триггер, то в эту таблицу можно добавить поле с дефолтным значением object_name(@@procid))

В этом поле запишется имя процедуры вызвавшей триггер.